# Can't install node.js v0.10.22 on linux because configure file missing

Tags: linux, node.js

I'm trying to install Node.js (v0.10.22) on a CentOS machine (64 bit) without internet connection. So far I:

- Copied "node-v0.10.22-linux-x64.tar.gz" to the desktop
- Ran `tar xvzf node-v0.10.22-linux-x64.tar.gz` to unpack it
- Moved to the new directory `cd node-v0.10.22-linux-x64`
- Tried to run `./configure`, but the file is missing

Is that a bad package? How can I get past this issue?

Comment: It looks like you downloaded the binary package, not the source package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tarballs that include an OS and architecture in the filename indicate pre-compiled tarballs. That means it includes binaries and not the actual source code for node. Typically you can just extract these tarballs to `/usr/local` or any other prefix that is in your `$PATH`.